# How to improve GBM performance

Tags: boosting, h2o

I'm trying to model insurance losses, with a Tweedie distribution. I have a data set of about 40 million records, and over 100 independent variables.
My response variable is "loss", I take the log of the exposure (time period) for the observation as the offset.  I ran a grid search on p-values to find p-values that produce the lowest residual deviance.

However, after performing a grid search my top model only finds a couple "important" variables.  Moreover, when I look at the scoring history, there seems to be improvement in deviance up to the first scoring event, then no improvement after.

[image]

This seems be similar across many models with learning rates ranging from .005 to .5.
The max trees is set at a couple of thousand, but the number of trees that the model produces never seems to go very high.

Comment: Do you have some evidence that a better model can be built? E.g. a baseline glm model, or a random forest model, etc.

Comment: I calculate a normalized gini for all models produced from a grid search and compare that to the existing model that was developed from a glm.

Comment: I've heard that GBM's are good at handling outliers, but I've never seen an example that deals with skewed data like I have.  For instance, at the 95th percentile the loss is 100,000, @ 99 its 250k.  I cap losses at 90k which is the 90th percentile.  
Is there a relationship between learning rate, trees, stopping_tolerance, and size of data?

Comment: What I meant was, how good/bad is your current result of deviance = 17.76 ? Maybe that is the theoretical best with the data you have and your data is done? On the other hand if you have a glm one-liner, on the same data, giving a deviance of 0.3, then something is very wrong. (And then your question is more likely to be a better fit at StackOverflow, and people will want to see your code, and some sample data, to be able to help.)

Comment: >  Is there a relationship between learning rate, trees, stopping_tolerance, and size of data?
That should be a fresh question (and I think you'll need to give some more insights into your data, or the answer will be an unhelpful, "Yeah, probably.")